# Order by frequency of occurence within a field

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to order based on the number of times something appears inside a single field?

Take the following data:

```
id, value
1, 'Bob'
2, 'Bob Bob Bob'
3, 'Bob Bob Bob Bob'
4, 'Bob Bob'
```

If I query:

```
SELECT id from table where value like '%Bob%'
```

Result would be 1,2,3,4 as they all contain Bob

I want it to order based on how many times Bob appears in each value so I would like 3,2,4,1 as the response as Bob appears most often in 3 and least often in 1.

```
SELECT id from table where value like '%Bob%' order by frequency_score
```

How do I calculate frequency_score?

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be like this:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     yourtable
WHERE    value LIKE '%Bob%'
ORDER BY LENGTH(value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(value, 'Bob', '')) DESC
```

please notice that this query won't match whole words, only substrings. If you need to match whole words you could use something like this:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     yourtable
WHERE    value REGEXP '[[:<:]]Bob[[:>:]]'
ORDER BY
  LENGTH(value) -
  LENGTH(REPLACE(CONCAT(' ', REPLACE(value, ' ', '  '), ' '), ' Bob ', '')) DESC
```